# Macro for merging cells

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have an Excel file with Invoice number in Column B, (`B2:B14987`), in Column C I have Item ID's, in Column D I have Sold Value, in Column E I have Invoice-Discount Value.

I need a macro to merge the Invoice Discount value cells based on Invoice number column, invoice numbers are repeated as there are different item ID's in one invoice.

For example: `B1:B3` are the same invoice number, `E1` is the common discount value for the invoices which are in `B1:B3`, `E2:E3` are blank cells. So I want `E1:E3` to be merged, with the value that was in `E1`.

Comment: To get a meaningful answer please read the FAQ with instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: please show us your code, and we'll help you fix it or improve it.

Comment: @ Philip, i have litle excel experience, not having idea on VBA, Please help

Comment: @davidb: Maybe you can start by recording a macro and then trying to amend the code to suit your needs?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? It sounds to me like a "Pivot Table" is just the thing you need, rather than a macro. Are you familiar with those? Could you show a simple example of (just a few lines) of your spreadsheet - "this is what I have, and this is what I want the result to look like"?

Comment: @Floris, after making a pivot, i have invoice numbers in column B, in column C i have product numbers (item id's), in column D i have sold value of each item, in column E i have discount amount given for total purchase for one invoice, for example lets say B2:B5 are same invoice numbers, but C2:C5 different item id's which are sold under the same invoice, D2:D5 is the sold values for each items, E2 has the Discount value for entire invoice, E3:E5 are blank, in this case E2 is common value for entire invoice, and i want cells E2:E5 to be merged as a single cell.

Comment: @davidb - it is getting much clearer now. So you mean you literally want to perform the "merge cells" command on groups of cells in column E that all have the same invoice number in column B, right? Can we assume that the cells have been sorted? Do you care about alignment of value in cell after merge?

Comment: @Floris - cells have been sorted, and value needs to be aligned in the center after merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does what I think you are asking for; as always, if I misunderstood, please clarify the question and we'll get there...

Create a Module in your spreadsheet, and paste in the following code:

```
Private Sub mergeAndAlign(r As Range)
    With r
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
End Sub

Sub mergeAll()
' step through column E
' merge all cells that have the same invoice number
' they are already sorted - and the value we need is in the first cell
' of the block to be merged
Dim r As Range
Dim prevItem As Range
Dim nextItem As Range
Dim lastRow, thisRow, rCount As Integer

lastRow = [B2].End(xlDown).Row

Set prevItem = [E2]
Set nextItem = prevItem.End(xlDown)

While nextItem.Row <= lastRow
  Set r = Range(prevItem, nextItem.Offset(-1, 0))
  mergeAndAlign r
  Set prevItem = nextItem
  Set nextItem = nextItem.End(xlDown)
Wend

' do the last item:
Set nextItem = Cells(lastRow, 5) ' last valid cell in column E
Set r = Range(prevItem, nextItem)
mergeAndAlign r

End Sub
```

Run the code from the sheet of interest. Click Alt-F8 to bring up the "macro" dialog - you should see the item "MergeAll" in the list (probably the only one).  It will take you from this:

[image: original spreadsheet]

To this:

[image: spreadsheet after merge]

Comment: @Floris-thanks u so much, this is what i wanted. thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. Once it was clear what you wanted it was relatively easy. Key is to ask very precise questions!