# Macro to merge and concatenate cells in Excel for rows in which information on other columns matches

Tags: excel, merge, concatenation, vba

apologize if this is a common post, but couldn't find something that fully applies to me.

It's a very similar post to (except that instead of just merging the 2 cells, i am looking to merge and concatenate): 
[Macro to merge cells in Excel for rows in which information in other columns matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547189/macro-to-merge-cells-in-excel-for-rows-in-which-information-in-other-columns-mat)

Referencing the image in the post above, what i am looking for are cells P2 and P3 to be merged and the data to be concatenated. For eg: if P2 had abc, and P3 had xyz, i am looking for end product to be abcxyz in the merged cell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. What i have only enables me to merge, but i am not sure how to concatenate it.

Sub Main()

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim sameRows As Boolean
sameRows = True

For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To 6
        If StrComp(Cells(i, j), Cells(i + 1, j), vbTextCompare) Then
            sameRows = False
        End If
    Next j

    If sameRows Then
        Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i + 1, 7)).Merge
    End If

    sameRows = True
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as your solution if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add this line in the code:

```
Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(i, 16).Text + Cells(i + 1, 16).Text
```

complete code:

```
Sub merge()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim sameRows As Boolean
sameRows = True

For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To 6
        If StrComp(Cells(i, j), Cells(i + 1, j), vbTextCompare) Then
            sameRows = False
        End If
    Next j

    If sameRows Then
        Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i + 1, 7)).merge
        Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(i, 16).Text + Cells(i + 1, 16).Text
    End If

    sameRows = True
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty straightforward: you store the first `String` inside a variable,

```
Dim FinalText As String

FinalText = Cells(i, 7).Text
```

add the second `String`

```
FinalText = FinalText & Cells(i + 1, 7).Text
```

then after merging the two cells, you write the content of the variable in your merged cell.

```
Cells(i, 7) = FinalText
```

I'm not going to give you the full solution though, since you copy-pasted what you found and wouldn't try to write something by yourself.

EDIT: if more than one cell is to be merged, I'd use the same technique, but using `FinalText = FinalText & Cells(i + 1, 7).Text` inside the condition that checks if the values contained in each cell is equal...

Comment: Thank you. Greatly appreciate the help. Working fine now. Another qn though: Is it possible to insert something in the code that doesn't bring up the "This selection contains multiple values..." message?

Comment: Yes, if it is only a matter of annoying messages, you can disable them inserting `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before the line of code that triggers the message. After you've done what you needed, remember to set it again to `True`

Comment: Thanks Noldor130884. After proof testing it on my worksheet, everything is good, except that in the case where there are 3 cells to be merged (because of common values), the text being copied over is just for the first 2 cells.If sameRows Then
            FinalText = Cells(i, 7).Text
            FinalText = FinalText & Cells(i + 1, 7).Text
            Cells(i, 7) = FinalText
            Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Delete