# Moving Data with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I received data in column F,G,H, and I. I need to get that all into column E and take out the duplicates and the blank cells. The code i have so far works but it puts them all in the same row and doesn't keep them on their appropriate lines. I need them to stay on the same line they are currently in but to just transcribe over into the other column. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Sample()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, i As Long
    Dim Rng As Range, aCell As Range, delRange As Range '<~~ Added This
    Dim MyCol As New Collection

    ~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Get all the blank cells
        Set delRange = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)  '<~~ Added This

        '~~> Delete the blank cells
        If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete  '<~~ Added This

        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

        lastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), _
        Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

        Set Rng = .Range("A1:" & Split(.Cells(, lastCol).Address, "$")(1) & LastRow)

        'Debug.Print Rng.Address
        For Each aCell In Rng
            If Not Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) = 0 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                MyCol.Add aCell.Value, """" & aCell.Value & """"
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next

        .Cells.ClearContents

        For i = 1 To MyCol.Count
            .Range("A" & i).Value = MyCol.Item(i)
        Next i

        '~~> OPTIONAL (In Case you want to sort the data)
        .Columns(1).Sort Key1:=.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958879/macro-to-merge-and-concatenate-cells-in-excel-for-rows-in-which-information-on-o to get a general idea of how to loop thru rows (instead of your cell loop).  This results in cells correctly being merged into one cell on same row.

Comment: Not sure of your problem.  Your code puts everything into a single column, and each onto a separate row.   And what, exactly. do you mean by "same line" ??

Comment: The same row they were on to begin with. hopefully these pictures will help. The first one is the before, second one is after. http://tinypic.com/r/dqtc5/9   http://tinypic.com/r/zmfvy0/9 .

Comment: I see, you are only removing duplicates if they are in the same row.  You can do that with simple formulas in column E, just pick up the first instance of a value in the columns to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub CopyThingy()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lCount As Long
Dim lCountMax As Long
Dim lECol As Long
Dim lsourceCol As Long

    lECol = 5 '* E column
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) '*Your Sheet

    lCountMax = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    lsourceCol = 6
    lCount = lCountMax

    Do While lCount > 1

        If ws.Cells(lCount, lsourceCol) <> "" Then
            ws.Cells(lCount, lECol).Value = ws.Cells(lCount, lsourceCol).Value
        End If
        lCount = lCount - 1

    Loop

    lCountMax = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    lsourceCol = 7
    lCount = lCountMax

    Do While lCount > 1

        If ws.Cells(lCount, lsourceCol) <> "" Then
            ws.Cells(lCount, lECol).Value = ws.Cells(lCount, lsourceCol).Value
        End If
        lCount = lCount - 1

    Loop

    lCountMax = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    lsourceCol = 8
    lCount = lCountMax

    Do While lCount > 1

        If ws.Cells(lCount, lsourceCol) <> "" Then
            ws.Cells(lCount, lECol).Value = ws.Cells(lCount, lsourceCol).Value
        End If
        lCount = lCount - 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Anytime :) Happy to help.